# Where did I go wrong with this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I already know many resolutions for this problem (which $y=\frac{1}{2}$ was the answer), but I was not able to find where I did a mistake in my original one:
\begin{align}
y &=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x - x^2  \ln{\frac{(x+1)}{x}} \right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} x \ \cdot \lim_{x \to\infty} \left( 1 - x  \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} \right)
\end{align}
Then,I tried to use l'hopital on the right limit(after some manipulations, such as spliting the limit in two (for each side of the subtraction) and "tossing" that x to the denominator in its inverse form so that I had $\frac{0}{0}$), but I ended up with
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}
\end{align}
Which would, in the end (multiplying again with the left limit I left in the beginning):
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{x}{x+1} = 1
\end{align}

Comment: Your second line is invalid. $\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) g(x)) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ is only true if both factors on RHS are defined. You end up with $\infty \cdot 0$, which doesn't work.

Comment: They didn't really end up using $\lim(fg)=\lim(f)\lim(g)$. So, not really the problem. The problem is in the part not mentioned, in obtaining the asymptotic $\frac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: @excitedGoose The factor $1-x\log(1+1/x)$ has Taylor expansion (at $\infty$) of the form $\frac{1}{2x}+o(1/x)$, not $\frac{1}{x+1}$. So, when you multiply by $x$, you get $\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\to\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

You fell into a trap for young players. The limit porpriety
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} g(x)
$$
is only true if the individual limits for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist and are finite. Consider, as a trivial example, the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x}
$$
which can be shown to be $1$ with no effort. However, if you tried to evaluate it as
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} x \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}
$$
you could be tempted to say that it doesn't exists because
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}
$$
doesn't.